# JAVA Hibernate +Spring HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Добрый день.
Время от времени появляется ошибка при попытке получить данные из базы БД(postgres).То  получается ошибка, то нет ошибки, не могу понять от чего зависит, на 3 запроса 2 с ошибкой обычно.

HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection

```
 type Exception report

message Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:980)....  и так далее.
```

Подскажите, что может быть?

Comment: А после "и так далее" больше никаких вразумительных сообщений нет? Нередко реальная причина ошибки выводится ниже по стектрейсу. Навскидку может быть 2 причины: проблемы с сетью, либо ограничения количества открытых соединений. Количество соединений может быть ограничено не только в самой СУБД, но и на стороне вашего ПО - в сервисе, реализующем пул соединений